# Reference web api from a different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing a MVC app. I want to develop some web api's so i can use them from other projects.

Can this be done as currently when i do create a web api project it creates all the controllers and views etc.

Also would this be the place where you setup the types e.g. contact type which contains all the objects for a contact e.g. name, address etc.

Just need to get it right before i get my head into it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perfectly fine define your Web API controllers (deriving from `ApiController`) inside separate projects (class libraries). The Web API is normally RESTFul and Web API controllers don't return views. They return models which are normally XML or JSON serialized. You could even host the Web API outside of an ASP.NET application in its own host which could be a Windows service or Console application for example. You don't even need IIS. The [following article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-Self-Host-30abca12) described a self hosting scenario.

As far as the consuming client side is concerned, that could be absolutely any kind of application ranging from desktop application to another ASP.NET site. The client application could use the native `HttpClient` class to consume the WEB API or any other HTTP capable client such as `WebClient` or even `HttpWebRequest`. The client could even be written on some other non .NET platform. All that is required is the capacity to send HTTP requests.

Comment: another note on this when i define my classes which contains types how would this fit in? So my web app and my web api would need to access the class type.

Comment: You could define them in a separate class library that you reference in both projects.